# Incorrect textures generated when using multiple Cube Cameras in three.js

Tags: three.js, textures

I have found an issue when using multiple cube camera's to generate textures for reflective spheres using MeshStandardMaterial, some of the textures are broken in unexpected ways the problem varies during the animation with the red sphere appearing perfect which may be related to it being the first camera updated.

I have tried manual clearing of renderer and render targets, setting auto-clear etc but nothing seems to work.

See example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pab_uk/9fxwojqk/16/

```
THREE.ColorManagement.enabled = true;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000);
camera.position.set(1.75, 1.75, 7);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.LinearSRGBColorSpace;

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}

const cubeRenderTarget1 = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(128, {
    generateMipmaps: true,
    minFilter: THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter,
});
const cubeRenderTarget2 = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(128, {
    generateMipmaps: true,
    minFilter: THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter,
});
const cubeRenderTarget3 = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(128, {
    generateMipmaps: true,
    minFilter: THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter,
});

const cubeCamera1 = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 10000, cubeRenderTarget1);
const cubeCamera2 = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 10000, cubeRenderTarget2);
const cubeCamera3 = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 10000, cubeRenderTarget3);

const pivot1 = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(pivot1);
const pivot2 = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(pivot2);
const pivot3 = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(pivot3);

const material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    envMap: cubeRenderTarget1.texture,
    roughness: 0.05,
    metalness: 1,
    color: 0xff4444,
});
const material2 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    roughness: 0.05,
    metalness: 1,
    envMap: cubeRenderTarget2.texture,
    color: 0x44ff44,
});
const material3 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    roughness: 0.05,
    metalness: 1,
    envMap: cubeRenderTarget3.texture,
   color: 0x4444ff,
});

const ball1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32), material1);
ball1.position.set(1, 0, 0);
ball1.add(cubeCamera1);
pivot1.add(ball1);

const ball2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32), material2);
ball2.position.set(3.1, 1, 0);
ball2.add(cubeCamera2);
pivot2.add(ball2);

const ball3 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32), material3);
ball3.position.set(1, 2, 0);
ball3.add(cubeCamera3);
pivot3.add(ball3);

const clock = new THREE.Clock();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    const delta = clock.getDelta();
    pivot2.rotateY(0.3 * delta);
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.autoClear = true;
    cubeCamera1.update(renderer, scene);
    cubeCamera2.update(renderer, scene);
    cubeCamera3.update(renderer, scene);
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

I have made no effort to make this example look nice this is just the minimal code that highlights the issue.

I guess my question is is there anything wrong with my code or is this a three.js bug that I should report?

Comment: Confirmed as bug in three.js which resulted in this PR which fixes the issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/27013, I assume this will be in the future v0.158 release.